# Matplotlib - how to align a second plot on a specific date that corresponds to a first plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `df` with 2 columns and I plot this with x-axis being dates and y-axis being the first data.

I then have secondary data associated with the first data in the following manner: The secondary data is a dictionary with `key` a date and `value` a vector. The date corresponds to a specific date that also exists in the first dataset (plot).

The vector includes past and future values in the sense that at index 20 of the vector, this value corresponds to the date (key).

I want to plot this aligned on the date with the first plot. Any solution would work (subplots, superimposition, two different axes).

I want ideally to have both dataset plotted in the same plot but correctly aligning the blue line as shown below.

Below is some toy code to illustrate an example and the problem:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

# data
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2020-11-30', periods=31),'temp':np.arange(1,32)})

# secondary data for date '2020-12-15', key is date and value is a vector. In this vector index 20 corresponds to the date '2020-12-15'
ml = {'2020-12-15':list(np.random.rand(56))}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1, dpi=120)
axes = axes.flatten()
axes[0].plot(df.date, df.temp, '-o', c='orange',  label='T')
axes[0].tick_params(which='major', labelrotation=90)
axes[1].plot(ml['2020-12-15'], '-o', c='blue', label='ML: 2020-12-15')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: (1) What says that index 20 of `ml` is the date you say? (2) What are the dates for the values before and after index 20? Do they correspond to the dates before and after, lining up by index?

Comment: @jared 1) by construction it is like this (the key is a date and the index 20 of the vector that is in the key, corresponds to the date). 2) yes the index 0 to 20 points in the 20 days in the past and index 21 to 56 point to 35 days in the future (again by construction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, there are two things you will need to do. The first is to create a list of dates that correspond to the values. I did this by making a pandas `DataFrame` for `ml` and then creating a `date` column that has the desired date at index 20. But if you just plot that, then the two axes won't line up. To fix that, you need to set `sharex=True` when creating the subplot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

np.random.seed(0)

# data
df=pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range("2020-11-30", periods=31),"temp":np.arange(1,32)})

# secondary data for date "2020-12-15", key is date and value is a vector. In this vector index 20 corresponds to the date "2020-12-15"
ml = {"2020-12-15":list(np.random.rand(56))}
date_index = 20
ml_df = pd.DataFrame(ml)
ml_df["dates"] = (pd.date_range(ml_df.columns[0], periods=len(ml_df)) 
                  - pd.Timedelta(date_index, "d"))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1, dpi=120, sharex=True)
axes = axes.flatten()
axes[0].plot(df.date, df.temp, "-o", c="orange",  label="T")
axes[1].plot(ml_df["dates"], ml_df["2020-12-15"], "-o", c="blue", label="ML: 2020-12-15")
axes[1].xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

P.S. You started using `plt` for the `tight_layout` and `show` at the end of your code. While that works, you should stick to one API, either the explicit "Axes" API (which is what you do when you create the subplots and use `ax`) or the implicit "pyplot" API (which uses `plt`). See [this link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#api-interfaces) for the documentation.

Comment: I agree - I was just about to post the same changes!

Comment: @jared thanks this works nicely. Any way to trim the start and end of x-axis so that the second plot covers only the range of the first plot?